# How to save 3D PhotoShop text and imaging as PNG or GIF...?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, png, photo-editing, gif

I've been working with PhotoShop for awhile. This has been the first time I've tried to save an image as a PNG or GIF and had it be an unavailable as a save file format.

Did some research, I believe I found a run around. Hopefully it will keep the image dynamic as it was intended. YouTube branding is fun, yet a dynamic logo is awesome.

I googled for quite awhile and found possible older versions of PS workarounds for this, yet nothing for CC 18.

So rather than attempting to "Save as", scroll down a bit to "Export", then slide over to "Save for Web(Legacy)". This allows for the image to be saved as a GIFF. This should retain image function and qualities as well as now being an allowed format for YouTube branding. Hopefully this helps others with this particular dilemma.

I am hoping this works and have solved my own question. Does anyone see an issue with this workaround?

Comment: Apparently this work around also lets you save works as PNG-8 and PNG-24.

Answer (score 1):

Using Save for Web or Export for PNG, GIF, or JPG images destined for the web is how you *should* be doing things. Save for Web/Export will often dump hidden data such as metadata which can enlarge the amount of kilobytes a file uses.

Another alternative is merely to **Save a Copy**. When saving, if a particular format is greyed out and unavailable, it is because there are things in your document which that format will *not* support. Photoshop tries to protect you from making the mistake of saving a file to a reduced format and losing your editing.

In the Save As dialog window, you can merely tick the "as a Copy` option...

[image]

Photoshop will **dump** whatever is necessary to *make* your open document fit the chosen format. That means it may flatten layers and remove transparency, etc. Since it is saving a *copy* there's no risk of you losing editing abilities in the open document.

Note that you can auto-tick the `as a Copy` option merely by holding down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key when choosing `Save As` from the menu. Or by adding <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> to the `Save As` keyboard shortcut.